# Wireless network configuration always reset the IP Static settings to DHCP - only for the GUI

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, wifi-configuration

In Windows 7 (My sister's machine) suddenly for the wireless network happened the following.
I did realize the static ip configured since time ago changed to other. So I returned to the `Properties` configuration for the `IPv4` option and arises the following:

[image]

The Figure comes from the solution of this case:

- [Solucion: Para configurar TCP/IP debe instalar y habilitar una tarjeta adaptadora de red](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5N7HQPV3WE4)

The message in English could be:

- `To configure TCP/IP you must install and enable a network adapter card drive`

**Question 1**

- Why this situation happened? - It is the first time in my life I had this behavior for Windows. Nobody played with the wireless settings. This case happened suddenly.

According with the video is enough uninstall the network card and detect new changes - and all done. Well it works How is expected - *even if the video is in Spanish is easy to follow*.

Therefore I can see again the GUI about `Properties` for `IPv4` and put the static data to configure a static IP and the respective DNS values. How it was used from the beginning.

**Note** the `ipconfig /all` command shows the *static data* and *dns ips* and appears `DHCP enabled` with `false`. The expected of course. And I have internet and Lan access in peace.

The main reason of this post. If I return to the GUI of `Properties` for `IPv4` I can see all the data empty - the default `DHCP` settings - the funny of this is that `ipconfig /all` keeps showing the *static data* and *dns ips* and appears `DHCP enabled` with `false` - as mentioned in the note.

I can re write the static data in the GUI, apply the new changes, open again the same GUI two seconds later and appears all reset - but the `ipconfig /all` command shows the static data mentioned.

**Question 2**

How fix this situation?

Comment: Reinstalling the Network Card reset TCP/IP .   Why are there still issues?  Try running SFC /SCANNOW from an Admin Command Prompt.  Restart when done and test.

Comment: @John I executed the mentioned command - no issues reported - restarted the laptop, but the situation remains. Other clue? Thank You.

Comment: Windows 7 has limited online repair capabilities and I listed them.  You can try repairing Windows 7 with the installation DVD. Start with this DVD and see if it offers you a repair option.